# How do I customize and use Phirehose functions?

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, stream, phirehose

I'm trying to put in a check for Phirehose to stop running after 10 seconds or 100 tweets...basically, I want to be able to stop the script.

I was told I could customize the `statusUpdate()` function or the `heartBeat()` function, but I'm uncertain how to do that. Right now, I'm just testing with the `filter-track.php` example.

How do I customize the functions, and where should I call them in the class?

```
class FilterTrackConsumer extends OauthPhirehose
{
  /**
   * Enqueue each status
   *
   * @param string $status
   */

  public function enqueueStatus($status)
  {

    /*
     * In this simple example, we will just display to STDOUT rather than enqueue.
     * NOTE: You should NOT be processing tweets at this point in a real application, instead they should be being
     *       enqueued and processed asyncronously from the collection process.
     */
    $data = json_decode($status, true);
    if (is_array($data) && isset($data['user']['screen_name'])) {
      print $data['user']['screen_name'] . ': ' . urldecode($data['text']) . "\n";
    }


  }

  public function statusUpdate()
  {
    return "asdf";
  }

}

// The OAuth credentials you received when registering your app at Twitter
define("TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY", "");
define("TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET", "");


// The OAuth data for the twitter account
define("OAUTH_TOKEN", "");
define("OAUTH_SECRET", "");

// Start streaming
$sc = new FilterTrackConsumer(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET, Phirehose::METHOD_FILTER);
$sc->setLang('en');
$sc->setTrack(array('love'));
$sc->consume();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop after 100 tweets, have a counter in that function receiving the tweets, and call exit when done:

```
class FilterTrackConsumer extends OauthPhirehose
{
  private $tweetCount = 0; 
  public function enqueueStatus($status)
  {
    //Process $status here
    if(++$this->tweetCount >= 100)exit;
  }
...
```

(Instead of `exit` you could throw an exception, and put a try/catch around your `$sc->consume();` line.)

For shutdown "after 10 seconds", this is easy if it can be roughly 10 seconds (i.e. put a time check in `enqueueStatus()`, and exit if it has been more than 10 seconds since the program started), but hard if you want it to be exactly 10 seconds. This is because `enqueueStatus()` is only called when a tweet comes in. So, as an extreme example, if you get 200 tweets in the first 9 seconds, but then it goes quiet and the 201st tweet does not arrive for 80 more seconds, your program would not exit until the program has been running 89 seconds.

Taking a step back, wanting to stop Phirehose is normally a sign it is the wrong tool for the job. If you just want to poll 100 recent tweets, every now and again, then the REST API, doing a simple search, is better. The streaming API is more for applications that intend to run 24/7, and want to react to tweets as soon as they are, well, tweeted.  (More critically, Twitter will rate-limit, or close, your account if you connect too frequently.)

Comment: Okay, I tried this. if I use `var`, it fails, and `$tweetCount` otherwise is always 1.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, got my languages confused; just fixed it with proper PHP class syntax!